# IntelliJ not displaying maven dependencies correctly

Tags: intellij-idea

Currently using maven Window Toolbar, I see

[image]

Is it possible to fix this to actually show what dependencies I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something appears to be broken with your project and/or IntelliJ. Here is what my dependencies display for a project:

[image: Maven Dependencies]

**Update:** Clicking "Reimport All Maven Projects" in the upper left corner of the maven toolbar window to refresh the Maven dependencies.

Comment: I agree. On my other machine things look as you have shown. I wonder whether this is a different view or possibly a configuration i can change

Comment: Did you try clicking "Reimport All Maven Projects" in the upper left corner of the maven toolbar window?

Comment: Yes, that seems to have refreshed things for me. Thanks